# USAR TEXTO EXTRAIDO VIA OCR PYTHON

Tags: python, text, ocr

eu consigo fazer a extração de dados de um PDF via tesseract, entretanto eu gostaria de usar uma informação extraida para renomear um arquivo de imagem com o texto extraído. Como poderia resolver? Abaixo o codigo de extração:
[Eu quero usar o texto marcado na imagem para utilizar em um outra variavel. Pegar o texto extraido para renomear um outro documento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT1NS.png)

import PyPDF2
import re
import pdfplumber as pdftool

#abrindo arquivo em modo leitura e lendo o binario
pdf_file = open('TESTE.pdf','rb')
#apos pegar o binario, pegamos os dados do PDF desse binario
dados_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

print('Numero de paginas ' + str(dados_pdf.numPages))
#setando a variavel pagina com o objetvo pagina 1
pagina1 = dados_pdf.getPage(0)
#pegando o texto extraido da pagina 1
texto_da_pagina1 = pagina1.extractText()

print(texto_da_pagina1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar expressão regular para extrair o ID do aluno em uma variável, ou se não quiser utilizar expressão regular, você pode procurar no texto o ID do aluno.

Utilizando expressão regular (recomendo muito dar uma olhada em https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
regex_aluno = r"Aluno:\s([0-9]*)"
...
match = re.search(regex_aluno, texto_da_pagina1, re.MULTILINE)
if match:
  id_aluno = match.group(1)
```

caso não queira utilizar expressão regular, você pode separar o texto em linhas, armazenando cada linha em uma posição da lista e procurando a linha que começa com *Aluno:* (não acho muito eficiente, mas é uma alternativa caso não queira partir pra expressão regular no momento).

```
...
linhas = texto_da_pagina1.splitlines()
for n in linhas:
  if n.startswith('Aluno: '):
    valores = n.split()
    id_aluno = valores[1]
...
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer alguns testes, não me entregou muito bem oque eu preciso. Sendo mais direto, apos a extração do texto via OCR, preciso identificar e usar o ID do aluno. Agradeço muito a contribuição eu estou lendo a documentação que me encaminhou!